# User versionName value of AndroidManifest.xml in code

Tags: android, android-manifest

The `AndroidManifest.xml` contains the version name of the application, something like

```
android:versionName="1.0"
```

Now the question - is it somehow possible to access this version name in the source code, so that I can display it for example in an About `Dialog`?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

If you use ADT and Eclipse:

```
String version = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
```

If you use Gradle, there is an easier way, since it puts the data into BuildConfig for you:

```
String version = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
```

Comment: That's too many "getPackage"s for a single line of code... O_O

Comment: Great! But is there a way to get the value from an xml file (especially to use it as `android:summary` of a `Preference` node)?

Answer (score 38):

Konstantin's answer (above) is correct, but for what it's worth I found that I got a compiler error if I did not catch a `NameNotFoundException` , as follows:

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
try {
    String version = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
}
```