# How can you get the Manifest Version number from the App's (Layout) XML variables?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-xml

I would like to have a way to reference the project's manifest version number in the main part of the code. What I have been doing up until now is to link the version number in a String XML file to the manifest (@string/Version). What I would like to do is to do it the other way around, link a string XML variable to the version in the manifest. The reason? I'd like to only have to change the version number in one location, the manifest file. Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: **If you're looking for how to do this *in Java or Kotlin code rather than in XML*, please see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3637665).**

Answer (score 104, accepted):

There is not a way to directly get the version out, but there are two work-arounds that could be done.

1. The version could be stored in a resource string, and placed into the manifest by:

   ```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.somepackage"
        android:versionName="@string/version" android:versionCode="20">
   ```
2. One could create a custom view, and place it into the XML. The view would use this to assign the name:

   ```
   context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
   ```

Either of these solutions would allow for placing the version name in XML. Unfortunately there isn't a nice simple solution, like `android.R.string.version` or something like that.

Comment: a little note to 1.: it's working but I think it's discouraged since I get a warning telling me `The android:versionName cannot be a resource url, it must be a literal string`

Comment: What I did is leave the manifest version name untouched (but update it whenever a new release) and use the string.xml to store the value that I'll be using across the app.

Comment: For `AndroidStudio`, the manifest `versionName` is override by the one set in `build.gradle` file

Answer (score 83):

You can use the `versionName` in XML resources, such as activity layouts. First create a string resource in the `app/build.gradle` with the following snippet in the `android` node:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.resValue "string", "versionName", variant.versionName
}
```

So the whole `build.gradle` file contents may look like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0 rc3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.myapplication'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 17
        versionName '0.2.3'
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.resValue "string", "versionName", variant.versionName
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
} 

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
}
```

Then you can use `@string/versionName` in the XML. Android Studio will mark it red, but the app will compile without issues. For example, this may be used like this in `app/src/main/res/xml/preferences.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="About"
        android:key="pref_key_about">

        <Preference
            android:key="pref_about_build"
            android:title="Build version"
            android:summary="@string/versionName" />

    </PreferenceCategory>


</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: Could you explain the "magic" (or my Gradle ignorance ;-) behind these lines?

Comment: @DenisGL

http://michiganlabs.com/string-constants-generated-gradle-build-configurations/#.VtB0-px96Um

Comment: This is better, than programmatic style.

Comment: Wonderful solution. Thanks a ton.

Comment: When I use this string in a layout, I get a warning from Android Studio: "Couldn't resolve resource @string/version_name". Any idea how to get rid of it?

Comment: @DenisGL have you add `variant.resValue "string", "versionName", variant.versionName` in `build.gradle` ?

Comment: this seemed like a great answer when I read it but sadly it doesn't work, at least not in the latest Android Studio.

Comment: I am using the latest and still works for me. I use this and several other variables like this. @k2col what error do u get while compiling? Pls post ur gradle code

Comment: This should be considered the best answer.

Comment: It worked but showing red mark|| error in xml though it runs

Comment: @A_rmas what is the error showing when you hover on the red highlight?

Comment: @ArunElectra it is cannot resolve symbol. but it allows run and generate apk. it is just the marking of error.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Tried to use it in my TextView but it says "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/versionName')."

Comment: this is the best solution , with this solution we can show different versions for different variants

Comment: Wow, great solution!!! Only bad thing is that AndroidStudio thinks that string is not recognised, but apk generates as it should!

Answer (score 17):

IF you  are using Gradle you can use the build.gradle file to programmatically add value to the xml resources at compile time.

Example Code extracted from:
https://medium.com/@manas/manage-your-android-app-s-versioncode-versionname-with-gradle-7f9c5dcf09bf

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        versionNameSuffix ".debug"
        resValue "string", "app_version", "${defaultConfig.versionName}${versionNameSuffix}"
    }
    release {
        resValue "string", "app_version", "${defaultConfig.versionName}"
    }
}
```

now use `@string/app_version` as needed in XML

It will add `.debug` to the version name as describe in the linked article when in debug mode.

Comment: best answer ever!!

Answer (score 15):

I solved this issue by extending the Preference class.

```
package com.example.android;

import android.content.Context;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class VersionPreference extends Preference {
    public VersionPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        String versionName;
        final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        if (packageManager != null) {
            try {
                PackageInfo packageInfo = packageManager.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
                versionName = packageInfo.versionName;
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                versionName = null;
            }
            setSummary(versionName);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my preferences XML:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <com.example.android.VersionPreference android:title="Version" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: Oops. I must have been thinking Preference XML based on another comment.

Comment: Nevertheless, I will just copy and paste his answer anyway.

Answer (score 15):

I use `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME.toString();`. What's the difference between that and getting it from the packageManager?

No XML based solutions have worked for me, sorry.

Comment: BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME is already a string, no need to call toString() on it.

Comment: Habit. Fair enough

Comment: There are cases when calling this in your project may get different result from what you would expect. For example if you use an android submodule in your project and you call it from the code of the submodule it will reference to build config of the submodule which may have different version. Or if you call it from the code of your project you may reference by mistake to build config of your submodule and get the same result. Just be careful and double check that you reference to a proper package of the build config.

Comment: Try using this guide: https://medium.com/@manas/manage-your-android-app-s-versioncode-versionname-with-gradle-7f9c5dcf09bf

Comment: difference is BuilConfig is provided by Gradle whereas getting it at runtime is by PackageManager (OS)

Answer (score 3):

You can't use it from the XML.

You need to extend the widget you are using in the XML and add the logic to set the text using what's mentioned on Konstantin Burov's answer.

Comment: I was afraid of that... Thanks for the help!

Comment: we can use it. please check my answer. I am using it in my app

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution is to use `BuildConfig`.

I use `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` in my application.

You can also use `BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE` to get version code.

Answer (score -1):

Late to the game, but you can do it without `@string/xyz` by using `?android:attr`

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="?android:attr/versionName"
     />
    <!-- or -->
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="?android:attr/versionCode"
     />
```

Comment: I use like this:`<Preference android:title="Version" android:summary="?android:attr/versionName" ></Preference>`, but show as `?16843292`.What's wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure but think this is for later API's?

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto actually, where does it say that?

Comment: doesn't work; returns funny number which @Suge pointed out above

Comment: doesnot work at all and returns random value as previously posted

Comment: as noted and linked It is a Constant Value of 16843292 (0x0101021c) hence why @suge got that specific value