# How can you get the build/version number of your Android application?

Tags: android, build.gradle, buildconfig

I need to figure out how to get or make a build number for my Android application. I need the build number to display in the UI.

Do I have to do something with `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471025/how-can-you-get-the-manifest-version-number-from-the-apps-layout-xml-variable

Comment: To get the version code use `int versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;` and to get the version name `String versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;`

Answer (score 2303):

If you're using the Gradle plugin/Android Studio, [as of version 0.7.0](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system), version code and version name are available statically in `BuildConfig`. *Make sure you import your app's package*, and not another `BuildConfig`:

```
import com.yourpackage.BuildConfig;
...
int versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
String versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
```

No Context object needed!

Also make sure to specify them in your `build.gradle` file instead of the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
defaultConfig {
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Comment: Beware, for a multi-module project you may get unexpected results when querying for this in a specific module. Probably best to bind this in some global name space in your main Application/Activity class.

Comment: This does not work if you want to use it in a library module to get info about the application. There's no BuildConfig file in the library module

Comment: @dumazy. there can be a BuildConfig for a library module but you won't be getting the application's build information. You will be getting the library's information.

Comment: I suppose the empty string result of this method is due to importing the wrong BuildConfig when writing this code. When I pasted it into my project I had a multitude of options to choose from for all libraries I was using and the modules as well. I just imported the one associated with my own package name

Comment: this is not working with `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0`

Comment: This doesn't work if your build gradle uses `versionNameOverride` to dynamically set the version. It will show whatever your gradle as `versionCode` has set, but this could be different then the value stored in your release. In case of the `versionName` It could be also different to what the store listing shows.

Comment: If using [gradle version 8.0 or higher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76576245/8890753), make sure you set `build.config = true` inside of `buildfeatures`

Comment: Can confirm, **does not work for android library modules**.  (You can reference a generated BuildConfig class for the library, but it does not contain a `VERSION_NAME` property despite specifying versionName in build.gradle)

Comment: I needed `buildConfig = true` inside of `buildFeatures`  instead of `build.config = true`. Kotlin vs Groovy maybe?

Answer (score 2210):

Use:

```
try {
    PackageInfo pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
    String version = pInfo.versionName;
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And you can get the version code by using this

```
int verCode = pInfo.versionCode;
```

Comment: @Felix you can't call getPackageManager() outside of context, so getApplicationContext() (or passed context) might be needed.

Comment: If you get null, check the AndroidManifest file: probably android:versionName is missing.

Comment: what if you need this number inside some static method where you can't pass the context? bad design on my part?

Comment: @Gubatron if you can't pass a context then I'd say your part :) you could simply just manage the version number in a static final field as well...

Comment: So  how to get the Playstore latest version ?

Comment: @ArslanAhmad Find the package name of the play store, and replace that with `getPackageName()`.

Comment: And don't forget to `try... catch..` when `getPackageInfo()`

Comment: Add a null check for pInfo.

Comment: For static context, store getapplicationContext() in a class which extends Application(Make sure you declare this class in manifest under application tag) and use it throughout your application.

Comment: @Gubatron my answer below allows to retrieve these values statically.

Comment: If you only want to get the application's version this is two compicated. You should use `BuildConfig.VERSION_**` as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21119027/5389530).

Comment: @AndroidGuy do we really need that? If the **running** app can't get its own package info, I would say a crash is very appropriate.

Comment: @TWiStErRob  In practice, you might also catch TransactionTooLargeException. Concurrent execution of the getPackageName often causes TransactionTooLargeException.

Comment: This answer is terribly outdated.

Comment: Just need import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;

Comment: `pInfo.versionCode` is deprecated in api 28

Comment: prone to bug and needs try catch

Comment: @Konrad Morawski Where exactly? Only versionCode is deprecated (but still available almost 4 years after your hardly helpful comment) and can be replaced by  getLongVersionCode().

Comment: @Aishik kirtaniya
"try...catch" was there years before your comment and what exactly do you mean with "prone to bug"? This works as expected.

Answer (score 494):

Slightly shorter version if you just want the version name.

```
try{
    String versionName = context.getPackageManager()
    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Excellent.  This should probably be surrounded with try/catch for NameNotFoundException.

Comment: +1 I've implemented your solution which works great! 
However, this solution should be surrounded by try and catch like Igor said AND it is good practice (e.g. for debugging) to put each method call on a separate line instead of calling context.methodName().subMethod().anotherSubMethod() etc. on a single line. Therefore I provided a cleaner solution [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18352981/1694500)

Comment: That's the right solution, thanks ;) But, as suggested by @IgorGanapolsky, it needs to be surrounded with try / catch :)

Comment: for those using Gradle - there is a simpler solution. See my answer below.

Comment: @Igor Ganapolsky: Just use Exception instead of NameNotFoundException to catch all possible exceptions, it makes your code/program more robust.

Comment: @Erwinus I wholeheartedly disagree with the notion of using a generic Exception to catch stuff like this.  More fine-grained exceptions demonstrate a developer's understanding of possible errors.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: That's true but what if the programmer don't understand it? I don't think the user of the application does appreciate any kind of exception. With all kind of Android flavors, there is a change that something unexpected happen and it will be stupid when something simple like this shutdown your app. If that happen, you can assume the programmer don't understand what the user wants because it's very easy to avoid this. Besides, you can log exceptions if you want to know what's going wrong, there is a description. No matter what kind of exception, an unhandled exception is wrong.

Comment: What are the cases when exception may be thrown? If the app is running and looking for self version is there a chance that PackageManager will not find it?

Comment: This is deprecated starting from Lollipop. Please be aware Android does not recommend this solution in production.

Answer (score 212):

There are two parts you need:

- android:versionCode
- android:versionName

versionCode is a number, and every version of the app you submit to the market needs to have a higher number than the last.

VersionName is a string and can be anything you want it to be. This is where you define your app as "1.0" or "2.5" or "2 Alpha EXTREME!" or whatever.

Example:

Kotlin:

```
val manager = this.packageManager
val info = manager.getPackageInfo(this.packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES)
toast("PackageName = " + info.packageName + "\nVersionCode = "
            + info.versionCode + "\nVersionName = "
            + info.versionName + "\nPermissions = " + info.permissions)
```

Java:

```
PackageManager manager = this.getPackageManager();
PackageInfo info = manager.getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
Toast.makeText(this,
     "PackageName = " + info.packageName + "\nVersionCode = "
       + info.versionCode + "\nVersionName = "
       + info.versionName + "\nPermissions = " + info.permissions, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Android's official description of `android:versionCode` and `android:versionName` can be found here:  http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html#appversioning

Comment: **this** in this case is Context .ie Activity, Service .etc

Comment: when you paste some sample code is usefull to explain the meaning of the parameters.... althoug everybody can understand what `this.getPackageName()` represents the `0` you just spit there has no clue about the meaning

Comment: Android Studio claims versionCode is deprecated

Comment: @RomanGherta It is as of API 28. If you are writing code using anything less (or 8 years ago when this answer was written) you should still be good to go. Another answer here has the updated method.

Comment: gives me a warning: "versionCode" is deprecated (on kotlin). What should I use instead?

Answer (score 158):

### Using Gradle and BuildConfig

#### Getting the VERSION_NAME from BuildConfig

```
BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME
```

Yep, it's that easy now.

#### Is it returning an empty string for VERSION_NAME?

*If you're getting an empty string for `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` then read on.*

I kept getting an empty string for `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME`, because I wasn't setting the `versionName` in my Grade build file (I migrated from [Ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant) to Gradle). So, here are instructions for ensuring you're setting your `VERSION_NAME` via Gradle.

#### File *build.gradle*

```
def versionMajor = 3
def versionMinor = 0
def versionPatch = 0
def versionBuild = 0 // Bump for dogfood builds, public betas, etc.

android {

  defaultConfig {
    versionCode versionMajor * 10000 + versionMinor * 1000 + versionPatch * 100 + versionBuild

    versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"
  }

}
```

*Note: This is from the masterful [Jake Wharton](https://plus.google.com/+JakeWharton/posts/6f5TcVPRZij).*

#### Removing `versionName` and `versionCode` from `AndroidManifest.xml`

And since you've set the `versionName` and `versionCode` in the `build.gradle` file now, you can also remove them from your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, if they are there.

Comment: This works great as long as you are accessing the BuildConfig from the application project, not a library used in the application project. Otherwise, you will get the BuildConfig for the library project, not the application.

Comment: @JohnCummings Interesting... didn't think of that.

Comment: Not working at all, `versionName "1.2"`, and `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` return `empty`. API > 21

Comment: As a follow-up, we actually stopped using this method in favour of just a static integer and a static String for the `versionCode` and `versionName`, respectively. Only because some tools like Code Push attempt to get your version number by parsing your `build.gradle` file and they can't full a dynamic value.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter PackageManager really is the safest option. If you use version code overrides for splits BuildConfig constant still holds the original (albeit flavored) value.

Comment: I've used this solution but I've found the flaw. If you have `2.6.23` and the next you want update on `2.7.0` then you get versionCode less than early. Therefore I applied this: `versionCode versionMajor * 10000 + versionMinor * 100 + versionPatch`
`versionPatch` is from 0 to 100

Comment: @JohnCummings it works if you `import com.package.name.BuildConfig;` or directly references it in code, even in a project lib ;)

Answer (score 61):

Here is a **clean solution**, based on [the solution of scottyab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616095/how-can-you-get-the-build-version-number-of-your-android-application/5788950#5788950) (edited by Xavi). It shows how to get the context first, if it's not provided by your method. Furthermore, it uses multiple lines instead of calling multiple methods per line. This makes it easier when you have to debug your application.

```
Context context = getApplicationContext(); // or activity.getApplicationContext()
PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
String packageName = context.getPackageName();

String myVersionName = "not available"; // initialize String

try {
    myVersionName = packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0).versionName;
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now that you received the version name in the String `myVersionName`, you can set it to a TextView or whatever you like..

```
// Set the version name to a TextView
TextView tvVersionName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_versionName);
tvVersionName.setText(myVersionName);
```

Comment: Do you think that NNFE can be really thrown? It would be weird to not find a running application in the package manager :)

Comment: I'm with you that it might be weird, but it's the default exception of this method - see [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29): it says `Throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException if a package with the given name can not be found on the system.`. However, I could not imagine a scenario for that!

Answer (score 60):

Use the following to get the app version or build code which is used to identify the APK file by its version code. The version code is used to detect the actual build configuration at the time of update, publishing, etc.

```
int versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
```

The version name is used to show the users or the developers of the development sequence. You can add any kind of version name as you want.

```
String versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
```

Comment: Out of all the answers, this is the simplest way. When you can do same thing with one line why do it with a 10+ lines of code. I don't understand that.

Answer (score 50):

### Kotlin one-liners

```kotlin
val versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE
val versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME
```

### Java one-liners

```java
String versionCode = String.valueOf(BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE);
String versionName = String.valueOf(BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
```

Make sure to import `BuildConfig` into your class.

Comment: Disadvantage of this approach is, in case you have this code in a library module, it will show you version of library, not an app itself.

Comment: In this case OP requested for an Android application, but thanks a lot for that note about the libraries, thumbs up

Answer (score 37):

Use the BuildConfig class:

```
String versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
int versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
```

#### File *build.gradle* (app)

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 17
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 25):

As in 2020: As of API 28 ([Android 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_9_Pie_(API_28)) (Pie)), **"versionCode" is deprecated** so we can use **"longVersionCode"**.

#### Sample code in Kotlin

```
val manager = context?.packageManager
val info = manager?.getPackageInfo(
    context?.packageName, 0
)

val versionName = info?.versionName
val versionNumber = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                        info?.longVersionCode
                    } else {
                        info?.versionCode
                    }
```

Answer (score 24):

If you're using PhoneGap, then create a custom PhoneGap plugin:

Create a new class in your app's package:

```
package com.Demo; //replace with your package name

import org.json.JSONArray;

import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;

import com.phonegap.api.Plugin;
import com.phonegap.api.PluginResult;
import com.phonegap.api.PluginResult.Status;

public class PackageManagerPlugin extends Plugin {

    public final String ACTION_GET_VERSION_NAME = "GetVersionName";

    @Override
    public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {
        PluginResult result = new PluginResult(Status.INVALID_ACTION);
        PackageManager packageManager = this.ctx.getPackageManager();

        if(action.equals(ACTION_GET_VERSION_NAME)) {
            try {
                PackageInfo packageInfo = packageManager.getPackageInfo(
                                              this.ctx.getPackageName(), 0);
                result = new PluginResult(Status.OK, packageInfo.versionName);
            }
            catch (NameNotFoundException nnfe) {
                result = new PluginResult(Status.ERROR, nnfe.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

In the plugins.xml, add the following line:

```
<plugin name="PackageManagerPlugin" value="com.Demo.PackageManagerPlugin" />
```

In your [deviceready event](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#deviceready), add the following code:

```
var PackageManagerPlugin = function() {

};
PackageManagerPlugin.prototype.getVersionName = function(successCallback, failureCallback) {
    return PhoneGap.exec(successCallback, failureCallback, 'PackageManagerPlugin', 'GetVersionName', []);
};
PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {
    PhoneGap.addPlugin('packageManager', new PackageManagerPlugin());
});
```

Then, you can get the versionName attribute by doing:

```
window.plugins.packageManager.getVersionName(
    function(versionName) {
        //do something with versionName
    },
    function(errorMessage) {
        //do something with errorMessage
    }
);
```

Derived from [here](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/db7f1b09bcae2bdb?pli=1&_done=/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/db7f1b09bcae2bdb?pli%3D1%26auth%3DDQAAAIUAAADHTpKQDhprc1z47kIpig_XDwwdijnmrz3n-Ppc8t4iBKMyBAYvlq5sgw85dETkxU2mjmAVjfZHLhsBK1n3EeD2g6eSUgZfmcads4Y8dyICbgsrmRe7qpXo_qN9Foydd7PQwwzB_UGI9kfEyNaGNtxvDWpAwDxrYlcrAFF3vOk0saebVeBNjDv2yIHZaAePwik&fwc=1) and [here](http://www.practicaldeveloper.net/2011/09/creating-plugin-with-phonegap-10.html).

Comment: The question was not about PhoneGap. Your answer might just confuse people.

Comment: @BobbyJ Nowhere in the question, title, or tags does it specify that the question was about a native application.  This is what came up on google when I was searching for the answer, and would have saved me several hours.

Comment: In this example you can see how silly it is to use third party solutions to create apps. When you wrote it yourself from scratch  it was just a couple of lines to code.

Answer (score 24):

There are two different scenarios in this question that are not properly addressed in any of the answers.

### Scenario 1: You are not using modules

If you are not making use of modules, you can access your BuildConfig file and immeditally get your version code with:

```
val versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE
```

This is valid because this is your app level BuildConfig file and therefor it will contain the reference to your application version code

### Scenario 2: Your app has many modules and you pretend to access the application version code from a lower module in your module hierarchy

It is normal for you to have many modules with a given hierarchy such as app -> data -> domain -> ui, etc. In this case, if you access the BuildConfig file from the "ui" module it will not give you a reference to the app version code but to the version code of that module.

In order to get the application version code you can use the following given code:

First an extension function to get the PackageInfo

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
fun Context.getPackageInfo(): PackageInfo {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.PackageInfoFlags.of(0))
    } else {
        packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0)
    }
}
```

Extension function to get the version code

```
fun Context.getVersionCode(): Int = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
    getPackageInfo().longVersionCode.toInt()
} else {
    getPackageInfo().versionCode
}
```

The approach for version name is similar:

```
fun Context.getVersionName(): String = try {
    getPackageInfo().versionName
} catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
    ""
}
```

Comment: Nice , however it should be an extension of Context rather than Activity

Comment: This is the only correct answer as of 2023.

Answer (score 21):

### No, you don't need to do anything with AndroidManifest.xml

Basically, your app's version name and version code are inside the **app level Gradle** file, under **defaultConfig** tag:

```
defaultConfig {
   versionCode 1
   versionName "1.0"
}
```

*Note: When you wish to upload an app to the play store, it can give any name as the version name, but the version code has to be different than the current version code if this app is already in the play store.*

Simply use the following code snippet to get the **version code** & **version name** from anywhere in your app:

```
try {
    PackageInfo pInfo =   context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
    String version = pInfo.versionName;
    int verCode = pInfo.versionCode;
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: versionCode was deprecated in API 28. As stated in the docs, use longVersionCode instead; https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#versionCode

Answer (score 20):

For API 28 ([Android 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_9_Pie_(API_28)) (Pie)), the PackageInfo.versionCode is deprecated, so use this code below:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
try {
    PackageInfo info = manager.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
    myversionName = info.versionName;
    versionCode = (int) PackageInfoCompat.getLongVersionCode(info);
}
catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    myversionName = "Unknown-01";
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Version name: BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME
Version code: BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE

Answer (score 15):

If you want to use it on XML content then add the below line in your Gradle file:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.resValue "string", "versionName", variant.versionName
}
```

And then use it on your XML content like this:

```
<TextView
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/versionName" />
```

Comment: I am getting in my xml the error: Cannot resolve symbol '@string/versionName'

Answer (score 14):

For [Xamarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xamarin) users, use this code to get version name and code

1. Version Name:

   ```
    public string getVersionName(){
        return Application.Context.ApplicationContext.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(Application.Context.ApplicationContext.PackageName, 0).VersionName;
    }
   ```
2. Version code:

   ```
    public string getVersionCode(){
        return Application.Context.ApplicationContext.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(Application.Context.ApplicationContext.PackageName, 0).VersionCode;
    }
   ```

Answer (score 10):

Always do it with a `try catch` block:

```
String versionName = "Version not found";

try {
    versionName = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
    Log.i(TAG, "Version Name: " + versionName);
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    Log.e(TAG, "Exception Version Name: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

Comment: Why should it be always?

Comment: @Peter Mortensen
You could declare the exception to be thrown, too, if you don't want to catch it in your current method.

Answer (score 9):

I have *solved* this by using the Preference class.

```
package com.example.android;

import android.content.Context;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class VersionPreference extends Preference {
    public VersionPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        String versionName;
        final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        if (packageManager != null) {
            try {
                PackageInfo packageInfo = packageManager.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
                versionName = packageInfo.versionName;
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                versionName = null;
            }
            setSummary(versionName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of Preference for the question here? PackageManager works without it.

Answer (score 9):

Here is the method for getting the version code:

```
public String getAppVersion() {
    String versionCode = "1.0";
    try {
        versionCode = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return versionCode;
}
```

Comment: Better method - BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE

Answer (score 9):

There are some ways to get `versionCode` and `versionName` programmatically.

1. Get version from `PackageManager`. This is the best way for most cases.

   ```
    try {
        String versionName = packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0).versionName;
        int versionCode = packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0).versionCode;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   ```
2. Get it from generated `BuildConfig.java`. But notice, that if you'll access this values in library it will return library version, not apps one, that uses this library. So **use only in non-library projects!**

   ```
    String versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
    int versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
   ```

---

There are some details, except of using second way in library project. In new Android Gradle plugin (3.0.0+) some [functionalities removed](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#variant_api). So, for now, i.e. setting different version for different flavors not working correct.

Incorrect way:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    println('variantApp: ' + variant.getName())

    def versionCode = {SOME_GENERATED_VALUE_IE_TIMESTAMP}
    def versionName = {SOME_GENERATED_VALUE_IE_TIMESTAMP}

    variant.mergedFlavor.versionCode = versionCode
    variant.mergedFlavor.versionName = versionName
}
```

Code above will correctly set values in `BuildConfig`, but from `PackageManager` you'll receive `0` and `null` if you didn't set version in `default` configuration. So your app will have `0` version code on device.

There is a workaround - set version for output `apk` file manually:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    println('variantApp: ' + variant.getName())

    def versionCode = {SOME_GENERATED_VALUE_IE_TIMESTAMP}
    def versionName = {SOME_GENERATED_VALUE_IE_TIMESTAMP}

    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        output.versionCodeOverride = versionCode
        output.versionNameOverride = versionName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This code was mentioned above in pieces, but here it is again all included. You need a try/catch block, because it may throw a "NameNotFoundException".

```
try {
    String appVersion = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
}
catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I hope this simplifies things for someone down the road. :)

Comment: Instead of try/catch you can also throw the exception again.

Answer (score 5):

For someone who doesn’t need the BuildConfig information for application's UI, however wants to use this information for setting a [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) job configuration or others, like me:

There is an automatically generated file, *BuildConfig.java*, under your project directory as long as you build your project successfully.

{WORKSPACE}/build/generated/source/buildConfig/{debug|release}/{PACKAGE}/BuildConfig.java

```
/**
* Automatically generated file. DO NOT MODIFY
*/
package com.XXX.Project;

public final class BuildConfig {
    public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
    public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "com.XXX.Project";
    public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
    public static final String FLAVOR = "";
    public static final int VERSION_CODE = 1;
    public static final String VERSION_NAME = "1.0.0";
}
```

Split information you need by a Python script or other tools. Here’s an example:

```
import subprocess
# Find your BuildConfig.java
_BuildConfig = subprocess.check_output('find {WORKSPACE} -name BuildConfig.java', shell=True).rstrip()

# Get the version name
_Android_version = subprocess.check_output('grep -n "VERSION_NAME" ' + _BuildConfig, shell=True).split('"')[1]
print('Android version: ’ + _Android_version)
```

Answer (score 4):

First:

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
```

and then use this:

```
PackageInfo pInfo = null;
try {
     pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
} 
catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}

String versionName = pInfo.versionName;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
package com.sqisland.android.versionview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView textViewversionName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    try {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
        textViewversionName.setText(packageInfo.versionName);

    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

```
try
{
    device_version =  getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.google.android.gms", 0).versionName;
}
catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Kotlin example:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.act_signin)

    packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES).apply {
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_version_name).text = versionName
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_version_code).text =
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) "$longVersionCode" else "$versionCode"
    }

    packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0).apply{
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_build_date).text =
            SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd hh:mm").format(java.io.File(sourceDir).lastModified())
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Alexander! I had the old BuildConfig code working in a project last year, but it's no longer working, so I used your code instead. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

```
private String GetAppVersion() {
    try {
        PackageInfo _info = mContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(mContext.getPackageName(), 0);
        return _info.versionName;
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}

private int GetVersionCode() {
    try {
        PackageInfo _info = mContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(mContext.getPackageName(), 0);
        return _info.versionCode;
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 3):

Example for inside Fragment usage.

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
.......

private String VersionName;
private String VersionCode;
.......


Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

/* Getting application version name and code */
try
{
     VersionName = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;

     /* I find it useful to convert vervion code into String,
        so it's ready for TextViev/server side checks
     */

     VersionCode = Integer.toString(context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).versionCode);
}
catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
{
     e.printStackTrace();
}

// Do something useful with that
```

Comment: You should look at other answers before posting your answer. e.g. for context you are doing getActivity.getApplicationContext if you are in fragment then i can understand but if you are in activity i dont think you would need to call getActivity

Comment: In my case I made that for Fragment. Code is used inside onCreate

Comment: If you use it in Fragment why not just use getContext()?

Answer (score 3):

***Mar 2024***
To retrieve the `VERSION_CODE`, simply you can use the `BuildConfig` class like the following code:

```
val versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE
```

Just remember, The `BuildConfig` class is automatically generated for all Android modules by default (Gradle Plugin 8.0.0+), **but** If you are using an *older version of the plugin* or using *custom fields* in your BuildConfig class, you will need to explicitly enable BuildConfig in your module's `build.gradle` file. (***like in compose projects***)

To fix the issue of importing `BuildConfig` in your `Jetpack Compose` project, follow these steps:

**1**. Add the below code in the `build.gradle`(app module) within android block.

android {

```
     //....
     buildFeatures {
        //...
        buildConfig = true // add this
        //...
     }
     //....
 }
```

**2**. Sync your project with the Gradle files(*the elephant button with a down arrow*). This step ensures that the build system applies the changes and generates the required code.

**3**. (*If the problem still persists*) Run **"invalidate cache and restart"** from the **"File"** menu.

**4**. Finally, Run **"Rebuild Project"** from the **"Build"** menu.

**⭕ :** Don't forget to import `import com.xxx.zzz.BuildConfig`

Answer (score 2):

```
PackageInfo pinfo = null;
try {
    pinfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
}
catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
int versionNumber = pinfo.versionCode;
String versionName = pinfo.versionName;
```

Answer (score 2):

As I had to get only the version code and check whether the app was updated or not, if yes, I had to launch the play store to get an updated one. I did it this way.

```
public class CheckForUpdate {

    public static final String ACTION_APP_VERSION_CHECK = "app-version-check";

    public static void launchPlayStoreApp(Context context)
    {
        // getPackageName() from Context or Activity object
        final String appPackageName = context.getPackageName();
        try {
            context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                  Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
        }
        catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                  Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" +
                                             appPackageName)));
        }
    }

    public static int getRemoteVersionNumber(Context context)
    {
        int versionCode = 0;
        try {
            PackageInfo pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            String version = pInfo.versionName;
            versionCode = pInfo.versionCode;
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return versionCode;
    }
}
```

Then I saved the version code using shared preference by creating a util class.

```
public class PreferenceUtils {

    // This is for version code
    private  final String APP_VERSION_CODE = "APP_VERSION_CODE";
    private  SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesAppVersionCode;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editorAppVersionCode;
    private static Context mContext;

    public PreferenceUtils(Context context)
    {
        this.mContext = context;
        // This is for the app versioncode
        sharedPreferencesAppVersionCode = mContext.getSharedPreferences(APP_VERSION_CODE,MODE_PRIVATE);
        editorAppVersionCode = sharedPreferencesAppVersionCode.edit();
    }

    public void createAppVersionCode(int versionCode) {

        editorAppVersionCode.putInt(APP_VERSION_CODE, versionCode);
        editorAppVersionCode.apply();
    }

    public int getAppVersionCode()
    {
        return sharedPreferencesAppVersionCode.getInt(APP_VERSION_CODE,0); // As the default version code is 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here i can give you solution to  access these version values programmatically within your Android application, you can use the **PackageManager**.

```
**try {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
        int versionCode = packageInfo.versionCode;
        String versionName = packageInfo.versionName;
        // Now, you can use versionCode and versionName as needed.
        // For example, you can display them in a TextView or log them.
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }**
```

Answer (score 1):

Useful for build systems: there is a file generated with your APK file called `output.json` which contains an array of information for each generated APK file, including the versionName and versionCode.

For example,

```
[
    {
        "apkInfo": {
            "baseName": "x86-release",
            "enabled": true,
            "filterName": "x86",
            "fullName": "86Release",
            "outputFile": "x86-release-1.0.apk",
            "splits": [
                {
                    "filterType": "ABI",
                    "value": "x86"
                }
            ],
            "type": "FULL_SPLIT",
            "versionCode": 42,
            "versionName": "1.0"
        },
        "outputType": {
            "type": "APK"
        },
        "path": "app-x86-release-1.0.apk",
        "properties": {}
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Log.e("TAG","VERSION.RELEASE {" + Build.VERSION.RELEASE + "}");
    Log.e("TAG","\nVERSION.INCREMENTAL {" + Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL + "}");
    Log.e("TAG","\nVERSION.SDK {" + Build.VERSION.SDK + "}");
    Log.e("TAG","\nBOARD {" + Build.BOARD + "}");
    Log.e("TAG","\nBRAND {" + Build.BRAND + "}");
    Log.e("TAG","\nDEVICE {" + Build.DEVICE + "}");
    Log.e("TAG","\nFINGERPRINT {" + Build.FINGERPRINT + "}");
    Log.e("TAG","\nHOST {" + Build.HOST + "}");
    Log.e("TAG","\nID {" + Build.ID + "}");
```

thanks to `https://stackoverflow.com/a/40421709/2828651`

Answer (score 1):

Just two methods

```
public static String getVersionName(Context context) {
    PackageInfo packageInfo;
    try {
        packageInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return packageInfo.versionName;
}

public static int getVersionCode(Context context) {
    PackageInfo packageInfo;
    try {
        packageInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return packageInfo.versionCode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just write this.

xml code

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/appversion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

initialize the variable for textview

```
TextView appversion;
```

set the textview id to variable

```
appversion = findViewById(R.id.appversion);
```

This is the main code to show the app version `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME`  just use it as string value

```
textview.setText("v"+BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Very easy:

**From Build**

```
   val manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER
   val model = Build.MODEL
   val versionRelease = Build.VERSION.RELEASE
```

**From BuildConfig**

```
 val versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE
 val versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME
```

Comment: This data is showing your device models and its android version. This has NOTHING to do with the version of your app.

Comment: You right, I will edit it

Answer (score -1):

```
try {
    PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
    String versionName = packageInfo.versionName;
    int versionCode = packageInfo.versionCode;
    //binding.tvVersionCode.setText("v" + packageInfo.versionName);
}
catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What is your answer adding with respect to previous answers? Please don't duplicate answers

Comment: An explanation would be in order.