# How do I get my application Version in Android

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me how to get the application version in Android?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the build/version number of your Android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616095/how-to-get-the-build-version-number-of-your-android-application)

Answer (score 150, accepted):

This [page](http://www.eridem.net/android-tip-008-getting-application-version-and-other-package-information) has a tips on how to do it from java:

```
PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
PackageInfo info = manager.getPackageInfo(
    context.getPackageName(), 0);
String version = info.versionName;
```

Also, [this link has official information on how to properly set up your application versioning](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html).

Comment: i m confuse about how to give update version to user ? Android market does it or we have to give user info about it please give me link documents about it

Comment: @nileshbirhade: Ask a separate stack overflow question about it.  Or try googling first.  That's how I got this answer

Comment: Someone attempted to edit the question to add exception handling, but simply swallowed the exception. It isn't clear to me in which cases the call to `getPackageInfo` will throw (somehow your application doesn't have a version specified?), and what is useful behavior in such a case. The edit didn't make that clear either, so I rejected it.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham actually, you HAVE to use a try-catch or it won't let you compile, it gives you an "unhandled exception: NameNotFoundException" at compile-time

Comment: @AbAppletic ah, forgot about checked exceptions (fortunately for me). Feel free to edit it then, as long as a useful fallback behavior is added, and probably the appropriate logging instead of silent swallowing of the exception (like the blog post I linked does).

Comment: can we use this BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME ?? @MerlynMorgan-Graham

Comment: @PoyyamozhiRamakrishnan I googled to find my answer, cause I was into trying to snatch up points w/ answers back in 2011. I think you can find your answer if you google. Also, you can just try it and see what happens.

Answer (score 75):

I am using Android Studio, I realized I could use one line code to get this.

```
/*version name*/
BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME

/*version code*/
BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE
```

**Edited:**

If you are using other android libraries, make sure you import **BuildConfig** from your application package. This is similar to the automatically generated R class for identifying resources.

Answer (score 14):

```
public int getVersion(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            return pInfo.versionCode;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

More info on this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/versioning.html)

Comment: GET_META_DATA seems to only apply for ComponentInfo, not PackageInfo: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#GET_META_DATA

Answer (score 12):

To get application information:

```
PackageManager manager = this.getPackageManager();
try {
   PackageInfo info = manager.getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0);
   String packageName = info.packageName;
   int versionCode = info.versionCode;
   String versionName = info.versionName;
   } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   }
```

Answer (score 10):

The easiest and best answer I found is to just import your BuildConfig

```
import your.package.BuildConfig;
```

then just

```
String verName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
int verCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
```

Comment: very important to import your package because I was getting "-1"

Answer (score 4):

If you are using eclipse try this:

```java
PackageInfo packageInfo = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
int versionCode = packageInfo.versionCode;
String version = packageInfo.versionName;
```

In Android Studio :

```java
int versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
String versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
```

make sure you have mansion version code in your module-level build.gradle file

Answer (score 2):

In your (Module: app) gradle define the version name and version code

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sing.smart"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1.0"
    }
```

**versionCode**

The versionCode is an integer value used to easily differentiate between app versions.

App developers must increment this value when they release updates to their apps in Android Market, so it can determine if users are using an old version of the app, and offer them to update it.

**versionName**

The versionName is a string containing a regular “release version” as seen in other desktop applications, such as “1.4.5” or “3.7”.

The versionName is just a “human readable” version code.

```
PackageInfo pinfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);  
int versionNumber = pinfo.versionCode;  
String versionName = pinfo.versionName;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the latest build gradle 8.0.0 or above in build.gradle (project level) like below

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0'
```

First, add below code in build.gradle(app module) within android block, and rebuild Project

```
android {
    buildFeatures {
       buildConfig = true
    }
}
```

then you can get version code and version name programmatically from your activity or fragment as follows:

```
int versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
String versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need it for scripting purposes (not for programming) you can use this command:

```
 adb shell "pm dump com.example.your.package.name | grep \"versionCode\"" | awk '{print $1}' | awk -F '=' '{print $2}'
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I need, except that you have to install the app to get this to work. I need something like this but without having to build the app at all. This is because I need the version number before my build happens (think to increment it)

Answer (score 1):

int versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;

String versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;

Answer (score 1):

**Java**

```
String versionCode = String.valueOf(BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE);
String versionName = String.valueOf(BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
```

**Kotlin**

```
val versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE
val versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

On Nativescript (with Typescript) one can do like this:

```js
import {Observable} from 'data/observable';
import * as applicationModule from 'application'

export class AboutViewModel extends Observable {
    public version: string;

    constructor() {
        super();
        let manager = applicationModule.android.context.getPackageManager();
        let info = manager.getPackageInfo(applicationModule.android.context.getPackageName(), 0);
        this.version = info.versionName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin :

```
fun getAppVersionName(context: Context): String {
        var appVersionName = ""
        try {
            appVersionName =
                context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(context.packageName, 0).versionName
        } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return appVersionName
    }



fun getAppVersionCode(context: Context): Long {
        var appVersionCode = 0L
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                appVersionCode =
                    context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(context.packageName, 0).longVersionCode
            }
            else{
                appVersionCode =
                    context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(context.packageName, 0).versionCode.toLong()
            }
        } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return appVersionCode
    }
```