# How to Get App Version Number In IOS Using Firemonkey?

Tags: ios, delphi, version, firemonkey

I am using Delphi 11 and need to get my app version number built in IOS. How to do it? In Android is easy but IOS I cannot find info.

Regards,

Thiago.

Comment: I am curious as to how it was "easy" in Android.

Comment: Like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6223785/3164070)? Doesn't seem much easier, unless by that you mean it was easier for you to find it?

Comment: find the info on the Internet I mean ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is one way:

```
uses
  Macapi.Helpers,
  iOSapi.Foundation;    

function GetAppVersion: string;
var
  LValueObject: Pointer;
begin
  Result := '';
  LValueObject := TNSBundle.Wrap(TNSBundle.OCClass.mainBundle).infoDictionary.objectForKey(StringToID('CFBundleVersion'));
  if LValueObject <> nil then
    Result := NSStrToStr(TNSString.Wrap(LValueObject));
end;
```

Note that in some cases you may wish to retrieve the value for `CFBundleShortVersionString` instead of `CFBundleVersion`.