# Android Application Update Notification

Tags: android, notifications, google-play

I uploaded my app to android market a month ago. Now I have uploaded its new version. I have old version installed on my device. But I have got NO update notification. Is there any option available to send update notifications to users when I update my application to Android Market?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not by default: the market notifications are not something exposed to app developers in any way. If you want to notify your users you'll need to build that into your app: set up a server that exposes an HTTP url that reports the latest version, then use an `AlarmManager` to call that URL and see if the version on the device is the same as the latest version. If it isn't pop up a message or notification and send them to the market to upgrade. Same thing described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298106/android-app-check-for-latest-app-version).

Comment: I think he is talking about the notification that the Market app sends out, and those should be automatic when uploading a new apk.

Comment: Understood. The Market generates those all by itself using a process that is completely opaque to the developer: there are no controls exposed to allow a dev to trigger those on demand, so you're stuck implementing your own checks in your app (as an example, I currently have a nag message from WhatsApp telling me to upgrade).

Comment: Completely agree, just made the comment to point that out. I learned something new from your answer so I am glad that you posted it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try This Library that checks for updates on Google Play, GitHub, Amazon, F-Droid or your own server. This library notifies your apps' updates by showing a Material dialog, Snackbar or notification  Check out the [wiki](https://github.com/javiersantos/AppUpdater/wiki).