# How to inform about app update for an app that is 'not in market' but on a drive, programatically?

Tags: android

I have made an app for my friends so that they can view class notes.The app is not  available on play store. Every time I update the app, I upload the new apk file to google drive.I want to write a simple code in my app that can inform if a new version is available or not.How can I do this?I don't want the user to automatically download the new version instead prompt the user to download the new version by clicking a button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notify user within app that a new version is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466516/notify-user-within-app-that-a-new-version-is-available)

Comment: But that is only for apps in the playstore market.My app isnt available on playstore.so i need the code for the exact same problem for an app not on playstore

Comment: How can people update your app when it is not on playstore (alpha beta or production ) channels , then you manually give it to them. If it is on any one of channels check the second answer with two votes.That is an efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

In the same Drive folder that you post your app, you can also put a text file, call it something like version.txt.  In this file, just put the version number of the latest version of the app.  It can be as simple as an integer that you increment each time you post the app.

Then at startup, your app can do the following:

1. Download the version.txt file, and note the version number.  Call this **V-Drive**.
2. If a locally-stored version exists, read it.  If not, save the value of V-Drive to SharedPreferences.  Call this **V-Local**.
3. If (V-Drive > V-Local) display a message telling the user that there is a new version available for download.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FABRIC](https://get.fabric.io/). Make registration and after that get the [CRASHLYTICS](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/summary)(A tool from Fabric made for testing purposes). It is quite easy to use and they are explaining step by step what to do in order to activated it. After that you can just add them in the list of testers and at the moment you release new version it will send them email with the updated app. I use it for work and it is working quite nice and it looks professional.

Good luck!!!