# Android popup that will only show up on App updates

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am trying for such a popup which will show up as a starting screen (like an agreement) , I know i can do the same thing with help of preference so that it wont show up again. But i want same popup to be showed only next time the app is updated.How can i do change the preference only when the app is updated?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `VersionName` as follows :

```
PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
String version = pInfo.versionName;
```

And get the `CodeVersion` doing :

```
int CodeVersion = pInfo.versionCode;
```

And then compare it every time and if it's different show the popup message.

You have more information on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298106/android-app-check-for-latest-app-version)