# add checking update function in android app

Tags: android

I want to add checking update function in android app

I know this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298106/how-to-allow-users-to-check-for-the-latest-app-version-from-inside-the-app) is asked already and post a lib on Github
 [How to allow users to check for the latest app version from inside the app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298106/how-to-allow-users-to-check-for-the-latest-app-version-from-inside-the-app)

but my cant i post on the Google Play Store due to some problem of copyright

So i cant use the method

what should i do?

Comment: if you are not posting on play store , then how will users install app from

Comment: just put it some where in a forum

Comment: like XDA something

Comment: then there is not even requirement of versioning. and since people are downloading from external source. they will need to download again from xda forum. i suggest it might be easier to use GCM and push a message to users that new update is available at xyz link

Comment: create a web service that will return your app version code. and once a day do check in your app. if it is greater than you should ask user to update app by your own method and if user says yes you can download apk from webservice and onDownloadComplete you can launch apk for installation.

Comment: but how should i do this @Pramod mishra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to check update once in a day. only works when you open app once in a day.    in onCreate() of your launcher activity.

```
SharedPreferences mSettings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences
                (Dashboard.this);
        long lastUpdateTime = mSettings.getLong("lastUpdateTime", 0);
        /* Should Activity Check for Updates Now? */
        if ((lastUpdateTime + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) < System.currentTimeMillis()) {

        /* Save current timestamp for next Check*/
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
            lastUpdateTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            editor.putLong("lastUpdateTime", lastUpdateTime);
            editor.commit();

        /* Start Update by using asynctask that run in backGround eg. http://portal.aksuniversity.com:8089/utility/apkversion*/
            String URL = "your app url in my case ;
            AsyncRequest asyncRequestTime = new AsyncRequest(Dashboard.this, "GET", null,
                    null, 3);
            asyncRequestTime.execute(URL);
        }
```

the response you will get is json object. get jsonObject key of version code and match it with your app version code

```
 int versionCode = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).versionCode;
            if (versionCode < jsonObject.getString(""VersionCode)) 
//if greater show dialog for app update and download apk with new url of your app which will give you apk
```

for download you can use

```
private String callApiDownload(String address) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL(address);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            if (Cookie.getCookie() != null)
                urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Cookie", Cookie.getCookie());

            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {

                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + folderName);
                boolean fileExist = true;
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    fileExist = file.mkdir();
                }
                if (fileExist) {
                    String FileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + folderName + "/"
                            + fileName;
                    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(FileName);

                    int bytesRead;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    int total = 0;
                    int contentLength = urlConnection.getContentLength();

                    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE) {
                            publishProgress((int) ((total * 100) / contentLength));
                        }
                    }
                    outputStream.flush();
                    outputStream.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    return fileName;
                }
            } else {
                InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getErrorStream());
                return fileName = Connection.convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
        return fileName;
    }
```

on download complete you can use intent to open apk for installation which will prompmt user for new update apk installation.

The first code will call the api once a day when user open the app. This api will return the json object of your app version code and version name. You need to manually maintain it when you create new apk for user.    Parse the json object. And get the version code. In your app check if api version code is greater than your app version code. And if it is than fire a new api which is the last code i have given that download the your apk from url(in server you have to place apk for specified urlby calling which your apk will downloaded) which is last code  you need to run in backthread asynctak. I will create the source code more proper and notifie you.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help .I am going to check it now

Comment: i am glad you got it. notify me when something went wrong.

Comment: however it would be better if you try to deploy your app in playStore.than there are other way which are easy.

Comment: my app is about psp rom

Comment: the game rom is made by CAPCOM

Comment: I still not to understand how to use it

Comment: but how about the seecond and the third one?

Comment: i have edited my answer. you can check if you have problem then ask again.

Comment: first create api that will return your app version code eg http://portal.aksuniversity.com:8089/utility/apkversion this can be static by you.means update version code manualy when you deploy new apk.