# How to install own paid app released in Android market on own Android phone?

Tags: android, google-play

Is there a way to install my own Android app on my Android phone so I can see and check how the updates work?

**I developed the app and released an update - I like to check myself how the update works.**

On iPhone there are the Promo Codes - what would one do on Android?
I tried to buy my own app - but that's not allowed.

So what can I do?

Thanks

Comment: why don't you create another account and buy it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't work that way. According to the Google documentation [here](http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=141659) about "Purchasing your own applications," it explicitly states that you can't buy your own apps. In the past, I've tested updates simply by installing over them because there really is not difference when it comes to updating. The private data doesn't get wiped and the user simply interacts with the upgraded app. Perhaps this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616095/how-to-get-the-build-version-number-of-your-android-application) on getting the version of your application can help.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check if the app updates correctly just install an older version of your paid app on your device and the market will then notify you that you have an update.

I am pretty sure there is nothing like a promo code in Android. Will do some more research and get back to you if I find something.

Comment: Sorry .. I gues I got confused coz I had tried with a free app :|

Answer (score 0):

Google Play has now native support for [promo codes](http://android-developers.blogspot.ie/2016/01/create-promo-codes-for-your-apps-and-in.html).