# Getting error when trying to retrieve versionCode from android app

Tags: android

anyone who knows what is going wrong? I am repeatedly getting this error when trying to retrieve the version code out of my manifest:

```
04-19 15:09:34.778: W/ResourceType(29293): No package identifier when getting value for           resource number 0x00000001
04-19 15:09:36.833: W/System.err(29293): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
04-19 15:09:36.843: W/System.err(29293):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:242)
04-19 15:09:36.848: W/System.err(29293):    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:304)
04-19 15:09:36.853: W/System.err(29293):    at com.koeriers.standaard.actUpdate.onCreate(actUpdate.java:71)
04-19 15:09:36.863: W/System.err(29293):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
04-19 15:09:36.863: W/System.err(29293):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
04-19 15:09:36.868: W/System.err(29293):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
04-19 15:09:36.873: W/System.err(29293):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
04-19 15:09:36.878: W/System.err(29293):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
04-19 15:09:36.883: W/System.err(29293):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
04-19 15:09:36.888: W/System.err(29293):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-19 15:09:36.893: W/System.err(29293):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-19 15:09:36.898: W/System.err(29293):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
04-19 15:09:36.898: W/System.err(29293):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 15:09:36.903: W/System.err(29293):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-19 15:09:36.908: W/System.err(29293):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
04-19 15:09:36.913: W/System.err(29293):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
04-19 15:09:36.918: W/System.err(29293):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-19 15:09:37.043: D/dalvikvm(29293): GC_CONCURRENT freed 211K, 14% free 9864K/11399K, paused 13ms+13ms, total 77ms
04-19 15:09:37.093: W/ResourceType(29293): Failure getting entry for 0x010802c0 (t=7 e=704) in package 0 (error -75)
```

and this is the code I use to retrieve the versionCode out of my manifest file:

```
int currentVersion = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionCode;
```

and ofcourse my manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.myapp.default"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
```

I hope you guys can help me out.

my onCreate method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Remove title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    TLogFile.appendLog("i", "UPDATER", "Updaten");

    // setting some display
    setContentView(R.layout.frmupdate);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Loading...");

    // making sure the download directory exists
    checkAndCreateDirectory("/downloads");

    try {
        int currentVersion = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionCode;
        Toast.makeText(this, currentVersion, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (NameNotFoundException n) {
        n.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // executing the asynctask
    new DownloadFileAsync().execute(fileURL);
}
```

Comment: Are you setting the `currentVersion` to textView..?

Comment: Can you please post the **onCreate** method ?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to put the `currentVersion` into a Toast. When you do so you need to convert it to a String or else it assumes you are refering to a String resource. Try something like this instead of what you have: `Toast.makeText(ctx, ""+ currentVersion, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()`

Comment: check my edited ans: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16105743/1168654

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the logcat states, you're getting a `NotFoundException` for a resource when trying to call `Toast.makeText()`. While I can't see any code connected to `Toast` in the question description, I will try to make a guess. There are two overloaded `makeText()` methods in `Toast`:

```
makeText(Context context, int resId, int duration)
```

and

```
makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)
```

Probably you're passing your `versionCode`, which is an `int`, as the second parameter, and while you want the second version of `makeText()` to be called, what gets called is the first one, where the `versionCode` is treated as the `resId`. There is probably no resource with this id and the error proves it. So what you need to do is to pass `String.valueOf(versionCode)` as the second argument, then the `Toast` will display the value of the `versionCode`.

Comment: I am using the first one, with the 'int resID'

Comment: You should use the second as Egor mentioned it, using **String.value ( versionCode )**

Comment: @user, When using this version of method, you should pass a resource id of a string that's defined in XML. If you want to display an int, you should "cast" it to String as described above.

Answer (score 1):

```
PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
version = pInfo.versionName;
```

check this ans: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6593822/1168654

### edited: change this line

```
Toast.makeText(this, ""+currentVersion, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using this vesionCode in any Toast. For Example If you want to show it in a textview tv

tv.setetext(versionCode);

so this is trigerring tv.setText(int resID);

But in your R.java there is no resource id with versionCode.

So to see the version code first convert it to String. then show it.

Comment: I gave example with settext, in your case it is toast