# Android versionCode programmatically

Tags: android, android-version

Is there any way to know dynamically and programmatically the versionCode of an Android application??

I don´t know... maybe something like

```
 getApplicationContext.getVersionCode();
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616095/how-to-get-the-build-version-number-of-your-android-application

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you're using gradle (default in AndroidStudio) you can:

```
BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE
```

Answer (score 3):

You find the following from using this code

```
 public int getVersionCode() {
    int v = 0;
    try {
        v = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionCode;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    }
    return v;
}
```

Class Required

```
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
```

Comment: This is more dynamic, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should be surrounded by a try...catch.

```
PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
version = pInfo.versionName;
versionCode = pInfo.versionCode;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE
```

and import

```
import com.<your_pakcage_name>.BuildConfig;
```