# Get android app version code (major, minor and patch) at runtime

Tags: android

How do you get the app version code at runtime? I have found many solutions to get the app version as a single integer. However I need the major.minor.patch version of the version code.

Comment: This question is already answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616095/how-to-get-the-build-version-number-of-your-android-application

Comment: The `versionCode` *is* "a single integer". It has never been in the "major.minor.patch" format. `versionName` *could* be in that format, but it does not have to be. There is no requirement for any developer of any Android app to use "major.minor.patch" for anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would mean to get the `versionName` that follows the [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) principles.

Get the `versionName`:

```
packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
    .versionName; // throws NameNotFoundException
```

Parse the `versionName`:

```
// check versionName against ^\d+\.\d+\.\d+$
final String[] versionNames = versionName.split("\\.");
final Integer major = Integer.valueOf(versionNames[0]);
final Integer minor = Integer.valueOf(versionNames[1]);
final Integer patch = Integer.valueOf(versionNames[2]);
```

DO make sure to handle all possible errors.

Comment: The problem was actually that I didn't know that versionName was what I needed.

Comment: I had to escape the dot to make this work, ie.: 
final String[] versionNames = versionName.split("\\.");

Answer (score 3):

you get it by this way

```
PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
    PackageInfo info = manager.getPackageInfo(
        context.getPackageName(), 0);
    String version = info.versionName;
    int code = info.versionCode;
```