# How to show app version on Preferences Activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity

Id like to add an my app version and possibly build on the my SettingsActivity.

Im trying to show an "About Phone" style activity on my app. But I dont know how to go about it.

I am currently using EditTextPreference in my preference.xml which calls a dialog on Click, but I want it to be like this, where the onClick event doesnt produce a dialog.:

[image: Nexus 5 screenshot]

SettingsActivity.java

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout)findViewById(android.R.id.list).getParent().getParent().getParent();
    Toolbar bar = (Toolbar) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tool_bar, root, false);
    root.addView(bar, 0); // insert at top
    bar.setTitle("Settings");
    bar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

}

pref_general.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:title="Settings">

<PreferenceCategory android:title="About" >
    <EditTextPreference
        android:title="Version"
        android:summary="@string/app_version"
        android:key="prefUsername"/>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

And one more thing, is there a way to get the app and build number from gradle via xml.

I know I code like a caveman and I usually manually update them in the strings.xml, but in my defense I am new to Android.

Comment: *I code like a caveman* -- don't beat yourself up, we've seen *a lot* worse here on SO ;) Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616095/how-to-get-the-build-version-number-of-your-android-application) to retrieve the build number of your app.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement bro

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I ended up with this.

[image]

Instead of extending classes and whatnot I went with this

SettingsActivity.java

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

public static final String TAG = "caveman";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);

    Preference pref = findPreference( "developer" );
    pref.setSummary("Marathon Apps");

    Preference pref1 = findPreference( "version" );
    try {
        pref1.setSummary(appVersion());
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout)findViewById(android.R.id.list).getParent().getParent().getParent();
    Toolbar bar = (Toolbar) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tool_bar, root, false);
    root.addView(bar, 0); // insert at top
    bar.setTitle("Prism");
    bar.setSubtitle("Settings");
    bar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}

public String appVersion() throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {
    PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
    String version = pInfo.versionName;
    return version;
}
```

}

pref_general.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory
android:title="About">
<PreferenceScreen
    android:title="Developer"
    android:key="developer"
    android:summary="Marathon Apps">
</PreferenceScreen>

<PreferenceScreen
    android:title="Version"
    android:key="version"
    android:summary="1.0">
</PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceCategory>


</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 16):

To get version name directly to preference xml without reading from java code

add this to gradle file

```
 applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.resValue "string", "versionName", variant.versionName }
```

That will inject string xml value with versionName

and in preference xml you can just get value

```
<Preference android:title="Version"
    android:summary="@string/versionName">

</Preference>
```

---

Complete gradle file for reference

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.resValue "string", "versionName", variant.versionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
```

Comment: @ValOkafor even its show as error, after compile and run it without issue. 
actually "applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.resValue "string", "versionName", variant.versionName }" this will inject varible versionName in build time. so don't add versionName in Strings xml either

Comment: `Lint` will show a complaint when viewing `preferences.xml`: _Cannot resolve symbol '@string/versionName'_ :( Not a big deal, but Google should fix that.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom [Preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html), overriding the [onClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#onClick()) method so that it does nothing. You can even extend the [EditTextPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html) if you don't want to re do everything from scratch.

Remember to include the fully qualified name for the class in the `pref_general.xml` file.