# How To Get Another App's Version Name

Tags: android

I want to get Minecraft Pocket Edition's versionName (Example 0.13.0.b5).

This is package of MCPE (Minecraft Pocket Edition)

```
com.mojang.minecraftpe
```

I want to get version to `String`. How can I do this?

My code to get package name:

```
List<PackageInfo> packages = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);

PackageInfo mypackage = <com.mojang.minecraftpe>;

String versionName = mypackage.versionName;
```

Solution:

```
try
    {
        PackageInfo eInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.mojang.minecraftpe", 0);
        changelog=eInfo.versionName;
        lol.setText(changelog);
        }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
    {}
```

Comment: mypackage.versionCode instead of mypackage.versionName.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616095/how-to-get-the-build-version-number-of-your-android-application

Comment: I dont want to get versionCode (70615005) I want to get versionName (0.13.0) (And I want to get another app's versionName. Not mine)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It gets the package info from the package manager (by package) and returns the version name.:

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.mojang.minecraftpe", 0);
return packageInfo.versionName;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add some explanation to your code: why does it works? What should it do?

Comment: it returns the version name of a specific installed application

Comment: @Aurasphere it gets the package info from the package manager (by package) and returns the version name. I think it's somewhat self-explanatory. Any `Context` has a package manager.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce "Short answers are ok, but full explanation is better", quoted from here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 2):

```
 List<PackageInfo> apps = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
 ArrayList<App> result = new ArrayList<>();

 for(int i=0;i<apps.size();i++) {
      PackageInfo p = apps.get(i);
      App newApp = new App();
      newApp.pname = p.packageName;
      newApp.versionName = p.versionName;
      newApp.versionCode = p.versionCode;
 }

 String minecraft = "com.mojang.minecraftpe";

 for (App name : result) {
        if (Objects.equals(minecraft, name.pname))
        String versionName = name.versionName;

 }
```

//----- class description ------

```
class App {
    String pname = "";
    String versionName = "";
    int versionCode = 0;
 }
```

If you want the version code, modify the 'if' condition in for loop with name.VersionCode.

Reference: PackageManager([Class for retrieving various kinds of information related to the application packages that are currently installed on the device.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html))

Comment: mypackage? Where is this variable declared?

Comment: @Skizo sorry typo. use 'name.versionName'. See the updated code.

Comment: unknown entity app info