# How to find whether particular app is installed on device and version number of that app in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to find whether a particular app is installed on device and retrieve the version number of that app. How can i do this in Xamarin forms? I need to implement this in both Android and iOS.

Comment: Not possible, at least not on iOS.

Comment: You need to create the **DependencyService** in xamarin forms to get the app version of both android and iOS

Comment: Not possible on iOS, for Android there are plenty of existing examples on SO and blogs on how to do this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**iOS:**

**Version:**

Retrieving the version number of other app in iOS is **impossible**.

**Is installed:**

But, if you know the **URL Scheme** of a third party app, you can use [canOpenURL(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl) to check if that app is installed on the device. If it returns `true`, it means the app is installed.

For example, you can check if Microsoft Outlook app is installed on the iOS device via the link `ms-outlook://` by using the following code snippet:

```
if(UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(new NSUrl(new NSString("ms-outlook://"))))
{
   //YOUR CODE...
}
```

Notice that, if it is in iOS 9 or above, you have to add the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in the info.plist to allow the url scheme, like this:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>ms-outlook</string>
</array>
```

**Android:**

In Android, you can use [PackageManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) and [PackageInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html) to check if any app is installed and the version of it.

There're some related SO cases you can refer to:

- [How to check programmatically if an application is installed or not in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392183/how-to-check-programmatically-if-an-application-is-installed-or-not-in-android)
- [How To Get Another App's Version Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33731052/how-to-get-another-apps-version-name)
- [Checking external app version name in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988958/checking-external-app-version-name-in-android)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Cin If my answer is helpful, can you accept it, like this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235? It's important to me!Thanks.