# How to get version code of dependency package?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the version code of a package compiled in a different project, and linked as a dependency into this one.  I make changes to both projects frequently, so I like to know version numbers.

The solutions here: [How to get the build/version number of your Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616095/how-to-get-the-build-version-number-of-your-android-application) shows how to get the version code from context, but that would yield the version code for packages in the current project, not dependent ones.

Here is the code I have tried (3-Scenarios):

```
public static int getPackageVersion(Context context, Class<?> tClass) {
    int versionCode = 0;

    //#1) Get Package name from class
    String packageName = tClass.getPackage().getName();

    //#2) Set Domain manually to top level package
    //String packageName = "com.somedomain";

    //#3) Get package name from context from this package
    //String packageName = context.getPackageName();

    Log.i(TAG, packageName);

    try {
        versionCode = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                packageName, 0).versionCode;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

        Log.e(TAG, packageName);
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    return versionCode;
}
```

#1) Shows how the method is originally meant to function, it uses the packageName for the class. Results in NameNotFound.

#2) I manually set the top level packageName for the dependent package, which is similar to what context.getPackageName() returns.  Results in NameNotFound.

#3) I use context.getPackageName(), and the code returns the version code of packages in this project -- as predicted, but not the result I need.

I have an inelegant hack already, I'm just storing the version number as a field on one of the classes, but a proper solution (if one exists) would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proper solution would be to use the BuildConfig file to store such values (for each project/subproject).
The Android Gradle plugin already contains these fields:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
}
```

Then get the field with `your.package.name.BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` or `your.package.name.BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE`

Comment: Is it yours? Because `BuildConfig.java` is definitely present on aar libs generated with gradle.

Comment: You are correct, BuildConfig class is generated in AARs -- that makes it easy.  I somehow missed it earlier when I went looking, and assumed it gets stripped out during the build.