# Showing One-Time PopUp (Welcome Screen)

Tags: java, android

This time I need a One-Time PopUp in my Application, which should check the App-Version and shows the Dialog only on the first start and if a Upgrade was done (Like from Version 2.1 to 2.2).

Here is my Code:

```
 //Pop-Up bei erstmaligem Start
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        // second argument is the default to use if the preference can't be found
        Boolean welcomeScreenShown = mPrefs.getBoolean(welcomeScreenShownPref, false);

        if (!welcomeScreenShown) {
            //Popup Show

            String whatsNewTitle = getResources().getString(R.string.whatsNewTitle);
            //Changelog Text
            String whatsNewText = getResources().getString(R.string.whatsNewText);
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle(whatsNewTitle).setMessage(whatsNewText).setPositiveButton(
                    R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }).show();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean(welcomeScreenShownPref, true);
            editor.apply(); //Needs to be set!
        }
```

This code works flawless, thanks to @Martyn. As I said before, there is one thing missing: A VersionCheck.

I have no idea how to get this and I hope someone could help me.

Comment: What do you mean by *version check*?

Comment: I need to check the unnderlined value, http://i.imgur.com/MLkvYIj.png. If its newer than, a hardcoded one, eg. 0.9, it should print a PopUp.
Dummycode:
if(Versionbefore != VersionNow){
//Show PopUp
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
// second argument is the default to use if the preference can't be found
Boolean welcomeScreenShown = mPrefs.getBoolean(welcomeScreenShownPref, false);
int savedVersion = mPrefs.getInt("savedVersiono", 0);
PackageInfo pinfo;
int currentVersion = 0;
try{
    pinfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
    currentVersion = pinfo.versionCode;
}catch (NameNotFoundException ex){

}

if (!welcomeScreenShown || (currentVersion > savedVersion)) {
   //Popup Show

    String whatsNewTitle = getResources().getString(R.string.whatsNewTitle);
    //Changelog Text
    String whatsNewText = getResources().getString(R.string.whatsNewText);
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle(whatsNewTitle).setMessage(whatsNewText).setPositiveButton(
                R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).show();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(welcomeScreenShownPref, true);
    editor.putInt("savedVersiono", currentVersion);
    editor.apply(); //Needs to be set!
}
```

Comment: PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
-> Unhandled Exception Error. NameNotFoundException

Comment: Put a `try-catch` block around it please.

Comment: I did and nothing happens. No PopUp. Do i need to set "savedVersion, 0" to a specific Variable?

Comment: With this code if no dialog is shown then it means `welcomeScreenShown` is true.

Comment: But my intention was to show it on first StartUp or if the App was Updated. 
I update the App, installed it and there was no PopUp. ^^

Comment: Try to debug what is the value of `welcomeScreenShown` and `savedVersion`

Comment: Updated my answer. Please try now.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

save versionName or versionCode after showing welcomescreen for first time.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean(welcomeScreenShownPref, true);
editor.putString("version", currentVersion);
```

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616095/how-to-get-the-build-version-number-of-your-android-application) for how to get versionName or versionCode.

```
String version = mPrefs.getString("version", "1.0");  //assuming 1.0 as first version of your app
if(!welcomeScreenShown || version.equalsIgnorCase(currentVersion))
{
    //welcome screen code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

store your version on welcome popup

check your version every time application starts

here is a code to get version

```
PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
String version = pInfo.versionName;
```

And you can get the version code by using this

```
int verCode = pInfo.versionCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PackageInfo pinfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
int versionNumber = pinfo.versionCode;
String versionName = pinfo.versionName;
```

Hope it will help you for checking version !