# How to get version any app in phone

Tags: android

I want to check any app version in phone ( android studio )
and if the last version equal the version install in users phones app
How to get any app version installed on the phone by Android Studio?

Comment: `BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE` provides the version code defined in your build.gradle file.

Comment: no , i'm talking >>> i miss the code to check any app in phone for example if you install facebook version 2 and now the current version 3 >>>>> app checked version facebook and tell you " your facebook app is not the last version "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate all application installed the app, then get each of the package name to get the package info.. in `packageInfo` have infomation about those app

```
final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> installedApplications = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

List<String> vers = new ArrayList<>();

for (ApplicationInfo appInfo : installedApplications)
{
    PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(appInfo.packageName, 0);
    vers.add(packageInfo.versionName);
} 

Log.i(TAG,vers.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all install app info:

```
 List<PackageInfo> packList = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
            for (int i=0; i < packList.size(); i++)
            {
                PackageInfo packInfo = packList.get(i);
                if (  (packInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0)
                {
                    String appName = packInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
                    ;
                    Log.e("App " + Integer.toString(i), appName +"  ver: "+packInfo.versionCode);
                }
            }
```

More info:[Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616095/how-to-get-the-build-version-number-of-your-android-application)