# Android - Versionsname in a Textview not work correct on appstoreupdate

Tags: android

I will show the Versionname of my app in a textview. have anyone an idea why this only changes if you reinstalled the app and not on an update?

```
String appversion = "Version " + context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
```

The reading works perfectly! My question was: I have an app with version 1.1 in the store. After an update to 1.2 the Textview still contains 1.1.(only on update) But if the app is reinstalled then 1.2 will be displayed. Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Elaborate the question, please!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the build/version number of your Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616095/how-to-get-the-build-version-number-of-your-android-application)

Comment: no duplicate please read the question correct... i not need how i can read the appversion/name. I need why are not change on update.. Reinstallation it work

Comment: Is it still happens if you are using `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME`?

Answer (score 0):

**You can get current version name using**

```
 String versionname = "";
    try {
           versionname = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    TextView versionname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textName);
    versionname.setText(versionname);
```

Answer (score 0):

**to get Version Name : use below code :**

```
public String getVersion(){
 PackageInfo versionInfo = getPackageInfo();
            String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name) + " v"
                    + versionInfo.versionName;
    return title;
}

  private PackageInfo getPackageInfo() {
    PackageInfo info = null;
    try {
        info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return info;
}
```

define your `context` If you are in fragment then
`context = getActivity();`
if you are in activity then `context = this`.

then set it to your textview like
`textview.settext(getVersion());`