# Android - How to get any application version by package name

Tags: java, android

I want to do some stuff in my own android application where I need to check some system applications versions before. (System & 3rd party apps)

How to do it in Android Studio?

In ADB I can dump it by:

```
adb shell dumpsys package com.samsung.android.calendar | grep versionName
```

but how to do it in code?

note: it's not duplicated question, none of solutions provided in comments works for me. I want to check ANY app version, not MY app

Comment: Hint: PackageManager

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the build/version number of your Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616095/how-to-get-the-build-version-number-of-your-android-application)

Comment: Cared to search? Already answered. One answer explains how to get the version of another application https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616095/how-to-get-the-build-version-number-of-your-android-application

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: we are able to get versionName and versionCode using this     Commend adb shell dumpsys package packgeName

Comment: Please try adb shell dumpsys package com.google.android.gm

Comment: I saw it but none of this command works for me. I want to check ANY application versin, not MY application

in this 'solution':
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616095/how-to-get-the-build-version-number-of-your-android-application
I have error 'no such method' in methods:
getPackageManager() and getPackageName()

+ I want to use it in UIAutomator module for my app, so it's 'androidTest' app, not Main application (my.app.package.TEST)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prolem solved, getPackageManager was not working because of lack of context:

```
try {
        Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        PackageInfo pInfo = pm.getPackageInfo("com.google.android.apps.photos", 0);
        String version = pInfo.versionName;
        Log.d(TAG, "checkVersion.DEBUG: App version: "+version);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: can you edit your question. in future you may get up vote