# android-gradle set versionNameOverride does not set versionName in BuildConfig.java

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

We have a `release` and `debug` buildType and want to set the `versionCode` and `versionName` to a constant value for `debug` as otherwise, every build repackages the apk, even without code changes.

So we set a fixed default `versionCode` and later override it for a specific buildType:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.gradletest"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        if (!variant.buildType.isDebuggable()) {
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                output.versionCodeOverride = getAppVersionCode()
                output.versionNameOverride = getAppVersionName()
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}
```

while this works for the apk, unfortunately the generated `class BuildConfig` always has the default `1/"1.0"` value. We read and show the `versionNumber` from within the app as this [popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21119027/1469472) suggests.

Apparently `BuildConfig.java` is generated at configuration, not at project build, so it can't know the chosen variant. How to handle this?

Our `getAppVersionCode()` is containing a timestamp, so every versionCode is different. I tried flipping the statements, so that the debug builds would show a different versionCode and versionName everytime, which would be fine for us.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode getAppVersionName()
        versionName getAppVersionCode()
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        if (variant.buildType.isDebuggable()) {
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                output.versionCodeOverride = 1
                output.versionNameOverride = "1.0"                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The reason why we have a fixed debug `versionCode` in the first place is that we don't want to rebuild all submodules for every code change. With the second variant, even though we set a fixed `versionNumber` for the debug build through `output.versionCodeOverride = 1` all submodules are rebuild by Android Studio. Before Android Studio 3.0 this worked but doesn't anymore. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed, `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` and `BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE` are automatic config fields that get set at time of configuration and unfortunately are not affected by using gradle scripts to set output override values.

Because they are automatic config fields, they also cannot be directly changed via gradle scripts either. Fortunately there are ways around this when using your approach:

1) Get the real version values for display from package manager:
Instead of calling `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` and `BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE` where you need to display them in app, call

```
val versionName: String = context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(context.packageName, 0).versionName
val versionCode: Int = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
             context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(context.packageName, 0).longVersionCode.toInt()
        } else {
            context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(context.packageName, 0).versionCode
        }
```

This will return the version values that you set via `output.versionCodeOverride` for the selected variant, even though the BuildConfig fields default to "1.0"/1

2) Add your own BuildConfig fields for app version
If you really want the version name to be accessible from BuildConfig, you can just build additional config fields when you set the output override values. Just be sure that you do NOT use the automatic field names of `VERSION_NAME` and `VERSION_CODE`:

```
android {

    ...

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        if (variant.buildType.isDebuggable()) {
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                output.versionCodeOverride = 1
                output.versionNameOverride = "1.0"                
            }
            variant.buildConfigField("String", "REAL_VERSION_NAME", "\"${getAppVersionName()}\"")
            variant.buildConfigField("Int", "REAL_VERSION_CODE", ${getAppVersionCode()})
        }
    }
}
```

then access using

```
val versionName: String = BuildConfig.REAL_VERSION_NAME
val versionCode: Int = BuildConfig.REAL_VERSION_CODE
```

Comment: We fixed this by now by moving to another build flavor for two different scenarios. Your solutions look good though, thanks :)