# unresolved reference BuildConfig

Tags: android, android-studio

When i'm try to rebuild my project i get the error below:

```
warning: flag is not supported by this version of the compiler: -Xallow-no-source-files
warning: flag is not supported by this version of the compiler: -Xjava-source-roots=/Users/tyln/AndroidStudioProjects/PhoneBox/base/navigation/build/generated/source/buildConfig/dev/debug
base/navigation/src/main/java/com/raqun/phonebox/navigation/IntentLoader.kt:7:9: error: unresolved reference: BuildConfig
        BuildConfig.PACKAGE_NAME,
        ^

> Task :base:navigation:compileDevDebugKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':base:navigation:compileDevDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details
```

When I check the class there're no unresolved references.

I'm using Gradle Version **3.3.1**

I almost tried everything such as `Invalidate Cache / Restart, Clean and Rebuild, Close and Reopen project, Reimport project, delete idea folder` etc but none of them worked.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Dis you find any solution?

Comment: no. i did not. :|

Comment: Just run the code solved my issue.

Comment: i tried every possible solution but none of them worked. but thanks for your answer.

Comment: this helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76124393/7234479

Answer (score 23):

Starting with android gradle plugin **8.0.0**, you now have to explicitly tell gradle that you want to generate the `BuildConfig` file.

**app/build.gradle**

```kotlin
android {

    //...
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
        buildConfig = true // <- set this to true
    }
}
```

Comment: THIS! you sir deserve more attention

Answer (score 20):

It's probably because you have not made a build since adding the field, **`BuildConfig` and other variables/properties declared in a Gradle file will only be available *AFTER* a successful build**. The following instructions will fix this:

- `Build -> Clean Project`
- `Build -> Rebuild Project` (comment any lines that cause compiler errors for now!)
- Press `Alt + Enter (Windows/Linux) or Option + Enter (macOS)` on `BuildConfig` in your code and select `Import...` from suggested solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to build your app by simply clicking on Build APK(s). Fasting way to fix it.

[image: build issue]

Answer (score 1):

after I clean and rebuild the project still facing the issue.

for me it was a typo at gradle file :S,
in your buildType check if there is a typo

```
buildTypes {

    deubg { <- it should be "debug"
        buildConfigField "String", "URL_BASE_DEBUG", '"https://example.example.com"'
        buildConfigField "String", "TOKEN_DEBUG", '"********"'
        buildConfigField "....."}


    release { 
        buildConfigField "String", "URL_BASE_PROD", '"https://example.example.com"'
        buildConfigField "String", "TOKEN_¨PROD", '"********"'
        buildConfigField "....."}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like variant. Remove special characters like : or , from root project folder name or in any path to project

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why even after cleaning, and invalidating caching or deleting entire ./gradle and ./idea folder won't help to fix this issue. I was using AGP and Gradle version 8.0.2 and 8.2.1 respectively, and now **I am using AGP 7.4.2 and Gradle 7.6.2** and after doing Rebuild, I see BuildConfig got resolved.