# How to get app Build Configuration (Debug or release) using JNI android?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, jnienv

I'm working on an so library in an android project. I need to check the Build Configuration(Debug or release) of the app on native code using JNI. What can be the best way to do it?

Comment: Gradle creates a `BuildConfig` class that has a `BUILD_TYPE` field. See this question: [How to get the build/version number of your Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616095/how-to-get-the-build-version-number-of-your-android-application) and adapt to JNI.

Comment: Sorry sir, But I'm looking for this solution inside a JNI Native library.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your package is `com.example.hellojni`, this grabs the `DEBUG` and `BUILD_TYPE` static fields from the `BuildConfig` class:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz )
{
    jclass cls_HelloJni = env->FindClass("com/example/hellojni/BuildConfig");
    jfieldID fid_HelloJNI_buildType = env->GetStaticFieldID(cls_HelloJni, "BUILD_TYPE", "Ljava/lang/String;");
    jfieldID fid_HelloJNI_debug = env->GetStaticFieldID(cls_HelloJni, "DEBUG", "Z");
    jstring jBuildType = (jstring) env->GetStaticObjectField(cls_HelloJni, fid_HelloJNI_buildType);
    jboolean jDebug = env->GetStaticBooleanField(cls_HelloJni,fid_HelloJNI_debug);
    const char * buildType = env->GetStringUTFChars(jBuildType, nullptr);
    std::string out = (std::stringstream() << "Build type is " << buildType << ", debug says " << (jDebug ? "debug" : "not debug")).str();
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jBuildType, buildType);

    return (env)->NewStringUTF(out.c_str());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, your answer is also going to solve many of my problems. :)