# How to get Version.Code in Android using C++?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I use native C++ with my Android project.

In Java or Kotlin we can use `BuildVersion.Code` to get the Android code from the Gradle file. How can I get this version code in C++?

Comment: Have you checked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60676462/how-to-get-app-build-configuration-debug-or-release-using-jni-android ?

Comment: yes its not working

Comment: "not working" is a terrible diagnostic. show us what you tried and how it fails.

Comment: sorry it was my mistake its working  thanks @Botje

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
jclass build_config_class = env->FindClass("com/example/app/BuildConfig");
jfieldID version_code_id = env->GetStaticFieldID(build_config_class, "VERSION_CODE", "I");
jfieldID version_name_id = env->GetStaticFieldID(build_config_class, "VERSION_NAME",
                                                      "Ljava/lang/String;");

int version_code = env->GetStaticIntField(build_config_class, version_code_id);
jstring version_name = (jstring) env->GetStaticObjectField(build_config_class, version_name_id);
```

You need to change **com/example/app** in the code to match your package name.