# Get count for number of times build for Generate Signed APK in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build, apk, generate

How to get the count for the number of times the Generate Signed APK is generated/build in Android Studio. Any way to do it programatically.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. What do you want to do with it anyway?

Comment: I want to make record and update to my UI like how many times build has been generated.

Comment: Than it's probably best to use the version code / name of your app instead.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. I recommend using the version code / name of your app. Here are a lot examples how to do so: [How can you get the build/version number of your Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616095/how-can-you-get-the-build-version-number-of-your-android-application)