Jetpack Compose: How to Get Build/Debug Config Info
I am looking to display VERSION_NAME etc in the app. However, Traditional ways don't work. BuildConfig isn't resolved. Maybe it needs to be imported?!
I tried to find a solution by web searching but had no luck.

try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616095/how-can-you-get-the-build-version-number-of-your-android-application?rq=2

Make sure BuildConfig.java is being generated, this is done by buildConfig = true flag in your app build.gradle.kts:
android {

   ...

   buildFeatures {
      compose = true
      buildConfig = true
   }
}

Then rebuild your project and Build config file should be generated.

oh this is akward you just need to have this in your gradle
   android {
        buildFeatures {
            buildConfig = true
        }
    }

then you can use BuildConfig with the import
import com.yourDomain.yourappName.BuildConfig

and all the variables will availables for you, if this does not work just clean project
