# How to get app versionCode from xml file?

Tags: android

How to get app versionCode which is inside `app build.gradle` from xml file? I know how to get it from java code, but I need to get it from xml file. Is it possible?

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 47 // I want to access this versionCode
    versionName "1.4.2"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

I have a file called `remote_config_defaults.xml` file under `res/xml/` where I increment version code every time manually.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- START xml_defaults -->
<defaultsMap>
    <entry>
        <key>APP_VERSION_CODE</key>
        <value>47</value> //here I want to get versionCode
    </entry>
</defaultsMap>
```

I use this file for Firebase remote config. I need to access versionCode from this file.

Comment: *I need to get it from xml file.* - are you sure? Why? This is not xml btw

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you get the Manifest Version number from the App's (Layout) XML variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471025/how-can-you-get-the-manifest-version-number-from-the-apps-layout-xml-variable)

Comment: @Tim updated my post.

Comment: This is still not possible! You'll still have to fetch the value "programmatically"

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    PackageInfo pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
    String version = pInfo.versionName;
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to bind these two values. The version code from gradle file will be generated during the build.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to create a String resource which will have the versionCode & then you can easily get it like @string/versionCode...

but you will have to update that string resource with the version code everytime you update your App...

Doing this programmatically will be more good & hassle free ;)

Comment: versionCode is not a string

Comment: @TimCastelijns did you read the answer? I said you will have to create one string variable with version code as value!

Comment: please tell me why would you put a variable that does not represent a string in strings.xml?

Comment: @TimCastelijns <string name="version_code">214</string>

Comment: I said why, not how

Comment: @TimCastelijns coz the OP needs to grab that value from XML, also I've said that he/she will have to update it with every build update