# How to know if an app runs for the first time on device?

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me how can I know if an app runs for the first time on an device? In my app I need to receive some data from a server only when app runs for the first time..

Comment: Maybe a duplicate.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217578/android-apllication-first-run

Comment: I think this link would be best according to code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617662/android-how-can-i-know-if-it-is-the-first-time-the-application-launched

Comment: Look here that code:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7217834/4039762
Enter this in your Activity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boolean flag to SharedPreferences or check if that data already exists in the system and retrieve only if needed.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with Jayp's answer, just want to make it a bit more clear. When you try to get a value from `SharedPreferences`, there are two scenarios:

1. Value indeed is there under the mentioned key and it's being returned.
2. Value is not created yet and a default value is returned.

You can try to get value, and if it's not created yet - means your app is being run for the first time. Then you can put a value under this key and next time when you try to get the value - you'll receive the value you've put there. Hope this helps.