# Check for Android Application is First run or not?

Tags: android

I am new to android development. I know we can check for application first run using preferences. But My Question is - If it is first run i should get a First(splash) form where i should get a string and save it in SQLite(Database). Second time i should check the database if the string exists I should get the Second(Login) form. I tried many ways its not working.

Can any one help me out with a detailed code. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I would use SharedPreferences for this purpose. Search for "SharedPreferences example" and you will find what you need. This is the most simple way to do it.

Comment: Even simpler would be to get rid of the splash screen, so you do not waste your users' time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just write an if else statement in the main method of the main page?
If first launch > splashscreen redirect
If run xx > Login redirect.

To detect the first time an app is launched you could make a sharedPreference (see this thread: [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values) or [Check if application is on its first run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217578/android-apllication-first-run))

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Define a startup activity without a view, and in its onCreate method, check (using SharedPreferences) if this is the first run. If so, go to the splash screen, otherwise go to the login screen.