# Check if android run for the first time

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to run a piece of code that will check if my app is first time installed and show my activity just like a tutorial(example: if a person installed a game their show some tutorial how to play the game) for the first time user. I have a 3 activity which is Splash screen, the main Activity and the profile. I don't know how to achieve it.

Comment: watch onto this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217578/check-if-application-is-on-its-first-run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing you can do is save a boolean in [sharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) when your app runs and then check for it everytime your app starts, something like this:

```
if (mySharedPreferences().appAlreadyRun) {
    //Your app has already been run at least once, so don't show tutorial
}
else{
    //Your app is running for the first time
    showTutorial();
    mySharedPreferences().appAlreadyRun = true
}
```

Notice that this won't work, it's just "pseudoCode" to help you get the idea. Hope it helps

Comment: i just solved my problem. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You should store a setting that you the user has runned it at least once.

If the settings is not there: first time
If the settings is there: n th time

You can store the setting using `SharedPreferences`: [link to Android Dev](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)