# actionscript make tutorial appear only once when launching game 1st time

Tags: android, actionscript-3

I maka a mobile game for Android and I need tutorial for my game that appears only once when game installed and opened first time. Is there a nice way to do it? What to add in my code for this?

Comment: You should use a shared preference which is checked at the start of your game. If isn't set you show the tutorial and set the (boolean) preference to true.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217578/check-if-application-is-on-its-first-run

Comment: You're question is very broad.  There are a whole lot of ways to do this. Essentially what you need to do save a boolean flag that indicates whether the user has completed the tutorial or not.   You could use a  `SharedObject`,  save a file with the `File` & `FileStream` class,  make a webservice or use a cloud service etc.     Consider updating your question to be  more specific and show what you've tried or explored so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to use a local [SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html):

```
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("data");

// when the tutorial is completed:
so.data.tutorialCompleted = true;

// before the tutorial starts
if(so.data.tutorialCompleted == true){
    // skip tutorial
}else{
    // start tutorial
}
```