# How can I keep track of the first launch of an application?

Tags: java, android, tracking, launch

How can I keep track of the first launch of my app and redirect user to another screen?
Please, give me example codes.

Comment: You can use Shared Preferences. This will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217578/check-if-application-is-on-its-first-run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is working for me:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    SharedPreferences prefs =getSharedPreferences("packagename", MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", true)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AnotherActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit();
    }
    else{}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean that from a launcher activity to anthor activity?If so, you can try this:

### In your Launcher Activity(MainAcitivity):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SharedPreferences preferences = this.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (preferences.getBoolean("firstLaunch",false)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AnotherActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        preferences.edit().putBoolean("firstLaunch",true).commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code isn't working. It shows the MainActivity always(

Comment: @SummerAugust Have you tried it? I tried it just now and it did work for me.When you first launch app ,you will come into MainActivity.Later you will come into AnotherActivity

Comment: check my answer below)

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake just now.When you first launch app ,you will come into AnotherActivity.And then ,when you launch app ,you will come into MainActivity.Am I right?

Comment: If you only use a `SharedPreference`,you can use `Activity.getSharedPreference(int mode)`

Comment: yes, you're right)

Comment: So where is problem with my code?Did you change it ?

Comment: where i can use this?

Comment: In your launcher Activity.

Comment: i already use this in my code: 

    SharedPreferences prefs =getSharedPreferences("packagename", MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: I mean if you use only a `SharedPreferences` object,you can use `getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)`

Comment: SharedPreferences prefs =getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); ?

Comment: Am I right? Or tell me how i need to write?

Comment: Yes  you are right

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: If my code is useful for you , you can accept it

Answer (score 1):

Use SharedPrefernces for storing the FirstLogin or not.

```
SharedPreferences prefs =getSharedPreferences("packagename", MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", true)) {
        // Do first run stuff here then set 'firstrun' as false
        prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit();
    }
    else{
       // Do if not first launch
    }
```

Comment: kai collage ma bhano cho patel bhai?