# Android: SharedPreferences Boolean

Tags: java, android, boolean, sharedpreferences

does someone know where the mistake is? There is an error in Android Studio.

The following is the code for now.

```
final String keyFirstTime = "keyFirstTime";

prefsEditor.putBoolean(keyFirstTime, false);

if (keyFirstTime = false) {
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, `keyFirstTime` is a `String`, so you can't assign a boolean value to it. And the expression in an `if` statement needs to be of `boolean` (or `Boolean`) type too.

Comment: Show full code please.

Comment: @BalkrishnaRawool nope, that's still a compiler error, because strings are never identical to booleans.

Comment: @BalkrishnaRawool and I'm saying that your suggestion is incorrect: it's just replacing one compiler error with another.

Comment: there is an error for **prefs.getBoolean(keyFirstTime) = false** too

Comment: Your code doesn't contain `prefs.getBoolean(keyFirstTime) = false`. But that would be an error because you can only assign to a variable; method results aren't variables.

Answer (score 2):

1. keyFirstTime is a string (see comment)
2. you are PUTTING a value not getting a value
3. You are using an assignment in an if statement
4. You are comparing a STRING to a BOOLEAN

In Activity 1 you should have:

```
final String keyFirstTime = "keyFirstTime";
prefsEditor.putBoolean(keyFirstTime, false);
```

In Activity 2 you should have:

```
boolean firstTime = prefs.getBoolean(keyFirstTime, false); //you don't need the editor
if (firstTime) {
    ...
}
```

Please go here for a tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

**EDIT** Try doing this (stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217578/check-if-application-is-on-its-first-run))

```
private static final String FIRST_RUN = "FIRST_RUN";
SharedPreferences prefs = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...

    prefs = getSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), MODE_PRIVATE);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (prefs.getBoolean(FIRST_RUN, true)) {           
        prefs.edit().putBoolean(FIRST_RUN, false).commit();
        //call relevant function for first run
    } else {
        //call relevant function for every other run
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but what if I want that keyFirstTime is true at the beginning (the first time that the user started the app) and change the value from true to false (if a button is clicked)

Comment: You can change the value at any point as long as you use the same string as the key in the SharedPreferences

Comment: You should mark this as the answer if it answers your question please

Answer (score -1):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences();  prefs.edit().putBoolean("keyFirstTime", true).commit();
```

Now to get Boolean value you have to use

```
Boolean check = prefs.getBoolean("keyFirstTime", false);
```

Now you can check this way

if(check){   your code here }