# Add configuration window to my apk

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to add a configuration window when installing my apk, so that window should contains an EditText, the value entered in that EditText will be used lately as a parameter in the application. How can i do that?

Comment: Just display a 'config screen' the first time the user launches the app

Comment: Try to use SharedPreferences to store local data configuration. see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217578/check-if-application-is-on-its-first-run?answertab=oldest#tab-top