# Does Android have an "onInstall" method?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am trying to log installs of my app using Firebase with this simple code below:

```
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("foo", bundle);
```

However, I am not sure where to put this code. Does any one know of an "onInstall" method in the Application class?

Or is there another, easier way to log installs with Firebase?

Thank you!

Comment: "Does any one know of an "onInstall" method in the Application class?" -- there is none. Nothing of your code is run when the app is installed, only when the user first launches your app.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense

Comment: The play store console already gives you nice statistics. However, you can log updates of your own app with the ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL broadcast action.

Comment: ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL was deprecated in API level 15. ([reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could determine if the user launches the application for the first time, and log that event.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    SharedPreferences prefs = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Perhaps set content view here

        prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.mycompany.myAppName", MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", true)) {
            firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("foo", bundle);
            prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Code referenced from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7217834/11016588).

There's another answer in that same [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217578/check-if-application-is-on-its-first-run) that explained how to differentiate between first run and subsequent upgrades, I'll just link that [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30274315/11016588) here for your reference.

The cleanest method would be to have a remote server that holds a unique ID for each user.

Also, you could theoretically write a file directly on the device. But then, you'd need to get the write permission and it's most definitely not a good idea to create and leave a file on the device.

P.S - To answer the actual question, No, Android doesn't have an `onInstall` method.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but after the user cleans the cache, won't the shared preferences be deleted as well?

Comment: Indeed, it's not a foolproof method. The cleanest method would be to have a remote server that holds an unique ID for each user.

Comment: You could theoretically write a file directly on device. But then, you'd need to get the write permission and it's most definitely not a good idea to create and leave a file on the device.

Comment: Thanks a lot pal!

Comment: No probs mate, mark the question as correct and upvote if it answered your question. Cheers.