# Open TapTargetSequence only on first use of app

Tags: java, android, tap, showcaseview

I have this tab target and it plays sequentially, please I want to display it as only once during the first time using the application, please explain how to do this

```
new TapTargetSequence(this)
        .targets(
                TapTarget.forView(findViewById(R.id.imgView1),
                                "Title 1", "This is image 1 click").tintTarget(false)
                        .outerCircleColor(R.color.dark_blue)
                        .cancelable(true),
                TapTarget.forView(findViewById(R.id.imgView2),
                                "Title 2", "This is image 2 click").tintTarget(false)
                        .outerCircleColor(R.color.dark_blue)
                        .cancelable(true),
                TapTarget.forView(findViewById(R.id.imgView3),
                                "Title 3", "This is image 3 click").tintTarget(false)
                        .outerCircleColor(R.color.dark_blue)
                        .cancelable(true))
        .start();
```

Comment: you can try the methods in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30274315/4205927)

Comment: My sincere appreciation to you, it has been resolved